The Shelah on doing teshuvah when eating
I heard in a shiur from Rav Daniel Glatstein that the Shelah HaKadosh explains that your table is like the mizbeach and your eating is like a korban, and every korban needs viduy.
So, the Shelah says, therefore before you eat, you need to say viduy and do teshuvah every time you are partaking of a meal.
Does anyone know where the Shelah (Shenei Luchos HaBris) writes this?

Similar: https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Shaar_HaOtiyot%2C_Kedushat_HaAchilah%2C_Emek_Beracha.6.6

@shmosel thanks I was right that it was in emek bracha maybe. Does this mean that saying over Divrei Torah atones for sins when eating a meal?

Something like that. Especially if you're sharing your meal with a needy person.

@shmosel in your link above, the Shelah mentions the Reishis Chochmah, citing the Yaavetz on Avos 3:3 and a posuk in Yechezkel. Do you know where I can find that, and what it says?

It's linked in the answer below: https://www.sefaria.org/Reshit_Chokhmah%2C_Gate_of_Holiness.15.149

@shmosel haha my bad, thanks!

I also listen to him, but I dont know if Shelah Hakadosh is a book or if it is a name of a person!Do you possibly have the link to this book?

@angie it is an acronym of the book shenei luchos habris by rabbi Horowitz. It is available on sefaria. Check the links below in thr answer.

שני לוחות הברית, שער האותיות, קדושת האכילה, מאכלות אסורות ז׳:י
In the notes, it says:

ולי נראה,
שכל אדם כשר יתוודה, ואז מקיים (תהלים נ, כג) זובח תודה יכבדנני, כי
האכילה היא במקום קרבן, ובכל קרבן היה וידוי לכפר על עונותיו, וסימנך
(איוב ג, כד) כי לפני לחמי אנחתי תבוא. ויתוודה וידוי אשמנו כו' הרשענו
כו' עד כי ירבה לסלוח. ובשבת ובימים טובים שאין אומרים וידוי, יאמר במקום
הוידוי זה הפסוק (דברים ל, ו) ומל ה' אלהיך את לבבך ואת לבב זרעך לאהבה
את ה' אלהיך בכל לבבך ובכל נפשך למען חייך, ולהרהר תשובה בלב


And it appears to me that all good men should confess, to fulfill
Tehillim 50:23 "whoever offers praise honours Me", for behold, eating
has taken the place of korbanot, and with every korban there was a
confession to atone for one's sins, and a sign for this is Iyov 3:24
"For my sighing comes before I eat".
He should confess from "Ashamnu" until "Ki Yirbeh Lislo'ach", and on
Shabbat and Yommim Tovim when we don't say Vidui, he should say the
pasuk (Devarim 30:6) "And Hashem your God will circumcise your heart,
and the heart of your children, to love Hashem your God with all your
heart, and with all your soul, so you may live." with thoughts of
Teshuva in his heart, in its place.

Note that there are many mentions of this concept of "eating in place of korbanot" in קדושת האכילה, and the phrase השלחן במקום המזבח - one's table is in place of the mizbe'ach appears many times too, including ibid 8:6, 8:9, 8:23, Emek Beracha 1:1. It is also discussed in ראשית חכמה, שער הקדושה ט״ו, which appears to be the source of this concept for the Shalah (both bring the Zohar in Teruma, 170a that explains how difficult it is for HKB'H to feed sinners), if not the original source in Shaarei Teshuva.

I don't see the quoted text at the link.

@shmosel It's in the note next to אז בצדקתו ובטהור מחשבתו מוריד השפע של מאכל

@zunior does it explain anywhere what one should do for bread? Does the viddui come before or after netilat yadayim? If after, I assume it must be before hamotzi, and is not a hefsek? Is this only for a seuda or is it for any eating and drinking?

Thanks Reb Kaii. This is exactly the text I was looking for :) Is this a note by the Shelah himself, or an author at Sefaria?

@Shmuel the notes are on the page of the Shalah. I believe they are from his grandson. Apologies we didn't start our chat about the 50 gates yet, glad I said bli neder. My father is in hospital, and I have been busy with that. Please daven for Michael Ben Miriam

thank you. No problem at all. I pray for a refuah shlema! May Hashem bless all that are in need of assistance! If you have the time, could you maybe please add in source(s) that explain that our table (literally the table we eat on), represents the mizbeach? That would be wonderful!

@Shmuel TY! Might expand later, but that will do for now ^
